# How do i get my MVC5 Application to work on my server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, localdb

I'm developing a simple MVC5 Asp.Net application using Entity Framework code first.

The application works using a LocalDB file (DefaultConnection.mdf). 
While locally everything works ok, moving the app to my IIS Server (Windows Server 2012 R2) does not produce the expected result.

I get the following error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred.
>   Cannot create an automatic instance.
>
> See the Windows Application event log for error details

I installed SqlServer LocalDB 2014 onto my Server but still get the error.

Any idea why that's happening?

This is my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 --></configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.0.0" newVersion="5.2.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Fixed: I Installed Sql Server Express on the server and configured Entity Framework to work with it.

Comment: Your config doesn't look correct. Why do you have connectionstrings in your configSections element?

Comment: Published the project again, connectionstrings was not there anymore, but the app still won't run. I suspect it's because i've got Localdb 2014 installed, but i'm configuring the app for localdb Version 11

Comment: I'd suggest you keep your database server on a separate server. This could not only cause security issues whereby your web server is publicly visible, but also your application and your database server will compete for the same CPU/memory/disk access resource.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your database set up in Localdb, remove your EDMX model from your project and add another one. When you do this, ensure that you connect it to the Localdb instance on your ***server***. This will create a connection string in your `web.config` file. For reference, the connection string should look something akin to:

```
<connectionStrings>
        <add name="Entities" 
             connectionString="metadata=
                 res://*/Context.csdl|res://*/Context.ssdl|res://*/Context.msl;
             provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
             provider connection string=&quot;
             data source=SERVER-IP-ADDRESS-OR-HOSTNAME;
             initial catalog=YOUR-DATABASE;
             user id=SQL-LOGIN;
             password=SQL-PASSWORD;
             multipleactiveresultsets=True;
             application name=EntityFramework&quot;"
             providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Except yours will be all on the same line.

Worth noting, when you run the application from your server, you can probably just use `localhost` as your hostname.

Comment: I don't have an EDMX file (sorry but i'm new to all this)